# How to find the index of a grid item before and after being dragged in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, grid

I am making a chess game with HTML, CSS and JS but i cannot figure out how to get the index of a piece in the grid before and after being dragged(i also use jquery and jquery-ui)

This is an image of the "game":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3qmG.png

**CODE HTML**

```html
<div class="chessboard ">
  <div class="cell white">
    <img class="piece" id="rook" draggable="true" src="assets/pieces/black/rook.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="cell black">
    <img class="piece" id="knight" draggable="true" src="assets/pieces/black/knight.png" alt="">
  </div>

  ..............................................

  <div class="cell black">
    <img class="piece" id="knight" draggable="true" src="assets/pieces/white/knight.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="cell white">
    <img class="piece" id="rook" draggable="true" src="assets/pieces/white/rook.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS**

```js
const pieces = document.querySelectorAll(".piece");
const grid = document.querySelector(".chessboard");
var grid_layout = []

// i tried to find at least the starting position by clicking on the pieces
pieces.forEach((piece) => {
  piece.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log($(piece.id).index())
  })
})
```

This is one of my failed attempts

```js
function GetElementIndex() {
  if ($('.piece').hasClass("ui-draggable-dragging")) {
    console.log(GetGridElementsPosition($('.piece').index()));
  }
}
```

This function returns the position of an element, given the index(which i am looking for), fortunately this one works quite well

```js
function GetGridElementsPosition(index) {
  const colCount = $(".chessboard")
    .css("grid-template-columns")
    .split(" ").length;
  const rowPosition = Math.floor(index / colCount) + 1;
  const colPosition = (index % colCount) + 1;
  return { row: rowPosition, column: colPosition };
}
```

Below is the function that enables the pieces to be dragged

```js
$(function () {
  $(".piece").draggable({
    start: function () {
      console.log("Starting Index:");
      GetElementIndex();
    },
    stop: function () {
      console.log("Ending Index:");
      GetElementIndex();
    },
    grid: [100, 100],
    activeClass: "dragging",
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

So due to some help from the comments i managed to get what i needed. I gave every cell of the grid an x and y value (like {1, 1} or {5, 8}) and i rendered the pieces through js and not html. I then found their current position by doing this:

```
var col = Math.ceil($(this).position().left / 100);
var row = Math.ceil($(this).position().top / 100);
```

This is just the piece being dragged(inside function in draggable())

Comment: I think it should be `$('.piece.ui-draggable-dragging').index()` otherwise you would try to get the index of all elements with the class `.piece`...

Comment: @biberman i tried it, but it did not work either!

Comment: Did you try to `console.log($('.piece.ui-draggable-dragging').index());` in the if statement of `GetElementIndex()`?

Comment: yes i did exactly as you said, but the result was the same as before, which is  {row: 0, column:0} in any block that i touch

Comment: But if you really tried `console.log($('.piece.ui-draggable-dragging').index());` you should have get a number...

Comment: well if you think about it that cant work since this class only exist when the object is being dragged, so after it has been released it does not exist

Comment: Because of that you should test it in the if block of `GetElementIndex()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way maybe to add at the html generation a position to the cells with `data-x` and `data-y`as custom html attributes? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: that is very interesting! i will try it and let you know

Comment: Please check the Browser support first, add an attribute like ```<div class="cell white" data-x="0" data-y="0"></div>``` and you can address custom attributes like ```parseInt(myElement.getAttribute("data-x"))```.

Comment: this isnt really the way i planned, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's very dependent on how did you implemented chessboard.
Btw you made me try to maky one myself :)

It' just board and moving pieces .. they cant attack or move properly (by the rules).

[Chessboard on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/JsonKody/pen/oNWJPNQ?editors=0010)

```js
const game = document.getElementById("game");
const squares = [];

const createSquare = (color, index) => {
    const el = document.createElement("div");
    el.classList.add(color, "square");
    el.dataset.index = index;
    el.dataset.color = color;
    game.appendChild(el);
    squares.push(el);

    document.addEventListener("click", movePiece);
};

let c = 0;
const createChessboard = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            let color;
            if (i % 2) {
                color = j % 2 ? "white" : "black";
            } else {
                color = j % 2 ? "black" : "white";
            }
            createSquare(color, c);
            c++;
        }
    }
};
createChessboard();

const playerWhite = {
    side: "white",
    pieces: {
        rook1: { name: "Rook", side: "white", index: 0 },
        knight1: { name: "Knight", side: "white", index: 1 },
        bishop1: { name: "Bishop", side: "black", index: 2 },
        king: { name: "King", side: "white", index: 3 },
        queen: { name: "Queen", side: "white", index: 4 },
        bishop2: { name: "Bishop", side: "black", index: 5 },
        knight2: { name: "Knight", side: "white", index: 6 },
        rook2: { name: "Rook", side: "white", index: 7 },

        pawn1: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 8 },
        pawn2: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 9 },
        pawn3: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 10 },
        pawn4: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 11 },
        pawn5: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 12 },
        pawn6: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 13 },
        pawn7: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 14 },
        pawn8: { name: "Pawn", side: "white", index: 15 }
    }
};

const playerBlack = {
    side: "black",
    pieces: {
        rook1: { name: "Rook", side: "black", index: 56 },
        knight1: { name: "Knight", side: "black", index: 57 },
        bishop1: { name: "Bishop", side: "black", index: 58 },
        king: { name: "King", side: "black", index: 60 },
        queen: { name: "Queen", side: "black", index: 59 },
        bishop2: { name: "Bishop", side: "black", index: 61 },
        knight2: { name: "Knight", side: "white", index: 62 },
        rook2: { name: "Rook", side: "black", index: 63 },

        pawn1: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 48 },
        pawn2: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 49 },
        pawn3: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 50 },
        pawn4: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 51 },
        pawn5: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 52 },
        pawn6: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 53 },
        pawn7: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 54 },
        pawn8: { name: "Pawn", side: "black", index: 55 }
    }
};

const setPlayerFigures = (player) => {
    for (let piece in player.pieces) {
        const thePiece = player.pieces[piece];

        const el = document.createElement("div");
        el.classList.add(player.side, "piece");
        el.dataset.id = `${player.side}~${piece}`;

        const text = document.createElement("span");
        text.textContent = thePiece.name;
        el.appendChild(text);

        squares[thePiece.index].appendChild(el);
        thePiece.square = squares[thePiece.index];
    }
};

setPlayerFigures(playerWhite);
setPlayerFigures(playerBlack);

let selectedSquare = null;
function movePiece(e) {
    const selectedPiece = selectedSquare && selectedSquare.childNodes[0];
    const clickedPiece = e.target.childNodes[0];
    const clickedSquare = e.target;

    // console.log(selectedPiece)
    // console.log(clickedPiece);

    if (selectedPiece === clickedPiece) {
        clickedPiece.classList.remove("active");
        selectedSquare = null;
        return;
    }

    if (selectedPiece && clickedPiece) {
        // trying to move to another piece
        // there will be code for 'take' the piece

        //FOR NOW just select another piece
        selectedPiece.classList.remove("active");
        clickedPiece.classList.add("active");
        selectedSquare = clickedSquare;
        // TODO --> delete this
        return;
    }

    if (selectedSquare && !clickedPiece && selectedPiece) {
        selectedPiece.classList.remove("active");
        clickedSquare.appendChild(selectedPiece);
        selectedSquare = null;
        return;
    }

    selectedSquare = clickedSquare;
    clickedPiece && clickedPiece.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
#game {
    border: 2px double gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
}

.square {
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: border 0.1s;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.square.white {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.square.white:hover {
    border: 2px solid #888;
}

.square.black {
    background: #444;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}
.square.black:hover {
    border: 2px solid #888;
}

.piece {
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.piece.white {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
}
.piece.black {
    background: #000;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
}

.piece.active {
    border-color: #20e320;
}
```

```html
<div id="game"></div>
```